# Any way to get the raw response when OAuth2 code is exchanged with Google+ iOS SDK?

Tags: google-oauth, google-plus-signin, oauth2client

I am integrating the Google+ sign-in using [Google's iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in). Upon a user successfully authenticating, the function `finishedWithAuth()` gets called, with one of the parameters being an instance of `GTMOAuth2Authentication`.

The client will need to send the credentials to the server, which is already using Google's [oauth2client](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) library. The server is already making use of the `Credentials` class that can be instantiated from the raw JSON response, so I'd like to be able to send the raw response to the server. However, it doesn't seem like the `GTMOAuth2Authentication` class exposes that from what I can tell.

Is there a simple way to access this, or is the simplest thing to do is reconstruct a "credentials" JSON object with the necessary information from the `GTMOAuth2Authentication` object ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use our new sign-in sdk for iOS and see 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth